# JitPack Maven PluginResolutionException

Tags: java, maven, jitpack

i want to use 
https://github.com/NiklasHoltmeyer/maven-endpointscoverage

without having to clone it:

https://jitpack.io/#NiklasHoltmeyer/maven-endpointscoverage

Pom.xml:

```html
<project ...

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>jitpack.io</id>
            <url>https://jitpack.io</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <!--
                 <groupId>de.hsos.bachelorarbeit.nh</groupId>
                  <artifactId>endpointscoverage-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                  <version>1.0.0</version>
                  -->
                <groupId>com.github.NiklasHoltmeyer</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-endpointscoverage</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0</version>
                ... config ..
            </plugin>
...
```

```
[ERROR] Plugin com.github.NiklasHoltmeyer:maven-endpointscoverage:1.0.0 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Could not find artifact com.github.NiklasHoltmeyer:maven-endpointscoverage:jar:1.0.0 in central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2) -> [
Help 1]
```

If i compile the Plugin and change the groupId / artifactId according to everything inside the Commentblock it works..

I also tried the following versions:

- 1.0.0
- master
- master-f2d0242df8-1
- master-SNAPSHOT
- -SNAPSHOT
- RELEASE
- LATEST

It would be great if someone could help me

Edit:

new Pom.xml:

```html
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>jitpack.io</id>
        <url>https://jitpack.io</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>jitpack.io</id>
            <url>https://jitpack.io</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

   <build>
        <plugins>
        ...
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.github.NiklasHoltmeyer</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-endpointscoverage</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0</version>
                ...
```

```
mvn dependency:resolve-plugins

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:3.0.2:resolve-plugins (default-cli) on project vet: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.DependencyResolutionException: Failure to find com.github.NiklasHoltmeyer:maven-endpointscoverage:j
ar:1.0.0 in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]

mvn clean install -U

[ERROR] Invalid plugin descriptor for com.github.NiklasHoltmeyer:maven-endpointscoverage:1.0.0 (C:\Users\nikla\.m2\repository\com\github\NiklasHoltmeyer\maven-endpointscoverage\1.0.0\maven-endpointscoverage-1.0.0.jar), Plugin's descriptor contains the wrong gro
up ID: de.hsos.bachelorarbeit.nh, Plugin's descriptor contains the wrong artifact ID: endpointscoverage-maven-plugin -> [Help 1]
```

Comment: Sounds like another problem. `mvn clean install` gives me `[ERROR] Invalid plugin descriptor for com.github.NiklasHoltmeyer:maven-endpointscoverage:1.0.0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your pom:

```
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>jitpack.io</id>
        <url>https://jitpack.io</url>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```

Because you are using a plugin. Your code with `<repositories>` covers only the dependencies, not the plugin dependencies.

Keep the rest as it is and run `mvn dependency:resolve-plugins` command to resolve you plugin dependencies.

---

Here is my working `pom.xml`

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>Sandbox</groupId>
    <artifactId>Sandbox</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>jitpack.io</id>
            <url>https://jitpack.io</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>jitpack.io</id>
            <url>https://jitpack.io</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src</directory>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.7.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.github.NiklasHoltmeyer</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-endpointscoverage</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:3.0.2:resolve-plugins (default-cli) on project vet: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.DependencyResolutionException: Could not find artifact com.github.NiklasHoltmeyer:maven-endpointsco
verage:jar:1.0.0 in central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2) -> [Help 1]

Comment: i even tried mvn dependency:resolve-plugins -u and mvn clean install -u

Comment: Did you add `pluginRepositories` tag as in my answer? From my log: `[INFO] Plugin Resolved: maven-endpointscoverage-1.0.0.jar`

Comment: @BarneyStinson Why did you remove `<repositories>` tag? I said to add `<pluginRepositories>` not to replace `<repositories>` with `<pluginRepositories>`.